# Is the delimiter in here document seen and used by the program which takes it as input?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

The format of here-documents is:

```
<<[−]word
here-document
delimiter
```

Is the delimiter seen and used by the program which takes the here document as stdin input?

Or is the delimiter used by the bash only, and not seen and used by the program which takes the here document as stdin input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your shell which used the here-document delimiter, the external program has no concept about it.

The shell did [Token Recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) and pass the here-document data to the program.

With a `strace`:

```
$ strace -s 10 -e read cat <<-IN
    1
IN
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0"..., 832)  = 832
read(0, "1\n", 131072)                  = 2
1
read(0, "", 131072)                     = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You see only the here-document data seen by `cat`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how to tell only the here-document data is seen by cat, from the output of strace?

Comment: what do the first `read` and the third `read` read then?

Comment: why does `cat` need to read an ELF file? Which ELF file?

Comment: do you mean remove `-e read`? Does `-e read` mean `-e read=all`?

Comment: @Tim: `strace -s 10 cat <<-IN`. And also, if all thing is clear, please remove the comments.

Comment: your deleted comments are helpful for learning strace. I recommend not to delete them.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not seen by the external program - the delimiter is seen and used only by the shell that runs the script.